# How do I use find_elements_by_xpath to only get some elements in python selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

How should I use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` to get all the data-row elements that I boxed in the picture.

[image]

I do not need the other `tr` tags. In my current code I just check all the `tr` tags and then throw out the ones that raise a `NoSuchElementException` but that gets very slow since my `implicit_wait()` is set to 15 seconds and the table is about 100 rows long, see below for code snippet.

```
table_element = t_find_element_by_id(driver, "table_name")
body_element = t_find_element_by_tag_name(table_element, "tbody")
row_elements = t_find_elements_by_tag_name(body_element, "tr")
for item in row_elements:
    column_elements = t_find_elements_by_tag_name(item, "td")
    try:
        a_tag_element = t_find_element_by_tag_name(columns[0], 'a')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below xpath.

```
//table[@id='table_name']//tbody//tr[not(@class)]
```

This will give you the highlighted tr tags.

Java Example:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='table_name']//tbody//tr[not(@class)]"));
for (WebElement ele : elements) {
System.out.println(ele.getText());
                        }
```